# Rewrite weird difference between servers

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Today I wrote the following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^visionale\.book [NC]
RewriteRule ^\/([^/]+)\/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?visionale\.se [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
```

The firs is for my laptop where I run Apache, the second rule for the web hotel.

Applying the first rewrite on the web hotel results in a 404 Not Found

Applying the second rule on my laptop mysteriously results in "pagename.php.php.php" not found.

Now the solution I provided works at both locations but I am baffled about what really is happening. My local machine runs Apache 2.4.6. The web hotel runs Litespeed. So this is an incompatibility of course, but exactly how.

My guess is that Litespeed misses the first rule because of missing functionality, but why does Apache not get the easier one, that I've used many times in the past?

Edit: Clarifying the questions.

This rule:

```
RewriteRule ^\/([^/]+)\/$ $1.php [L]
```

Is not picked on my web hotel running Litespeed. My guess is that this is because Litespeed has a flawed rewrite implementation. I'd like to get that hunch confirmed or another explanation privided.

This rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
```

Does not work on my dev-machine **any more** but it has worked in the past. It seems simple enough. Anything ending with a trailing slash should instead get a ".php" extension. However, on my dev machine it adds three ".php" instead of one. The rule works as intended in the web hotel and it has worked for me locally in the past. This is puzzling and I would like an explanation.

Comment: The patterns used in the two `RewriteCond` are different so how are you comparing them ? Your question is not pretty clear, could you please explain further ?

Comment: Yes they are technically different but they achieve the same result. foo/ is rewritten as foo.php.

Comment: For the problem on your dev machine, enable rewrite logging – then you can retrace exactly how that rule is being processed.

Answer (score 0):

Both rules are incorrect. Let me provide you correct code first:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^visionale\.book$ [NC]
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?visionale\.se$ [NC]
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Now the problems in your code:

1. `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess` doesn't start matching with leading slash which is striped by `mod_rewrite`
2. You need to avoid rematching these rules using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` otherwise `mod_rewrite` will keep adding `.php` in the URI.

Comment: I have clarified the question. (1) You may be correct about stripping away the leading slash in theory, however on my local machine the code I provided achieved the desired result as it was written. I will investigate if your version works on the web hotel, though. (2) The second rule might very well need the added condition. Without it, it still works though, on the web hotel and on my local machine it has worked in the past.

Comment: Additionally, if mod_rewrite really is supposed to keep adding ".php" several times when encountering the second rule as I wrote it, I would really like to know when and why this altered behavior was added.

Comment: Not really sure how it worked for you, may be because of `Litespeed`. mod_rewrite in Apache behaves differently and it injects resulting URL again through your rules and if conditions match again then rule is applied again. That's why `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is placed so that subsequent application is not used.